# Best exponential function algorithm, coefficients and errors?

Tags: matlab, exponential

I have experimental data for exponential distribution `a*exp(b*x)`. the objetive is to find the coefficients a, b and their errors.

I have tried using the function `fit(B,C, 'exp1')` and got some results.

Currently i'm experimenting problems because some data points in my file have higher error rate due to the nature of the experiment.

The concrete questions are:

1. Which algorithm or function in Matlab can give the smallest error ?
2. How can I use/adopt some function in Matlab to put smaller weight (when I calculate coefficients) on data that drastically differ from exponential function ?

Comment: Does one of the answers help you? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `fitoptions` argument to specify weights for the fit, or exclude some data points. See  the [`fit` documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/curvefit/fit.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are talking about the exponential *distribution*? If yes, I'm assuming you computed a histogram and now want to fit a line to the histogram. But that's not the best approach.

First, note that the probability density function of the exponential distribution has only a single parameter, due to the normalization of the pdf. The expression for the density is

```
lambda * exp(-lambda * x)
```

Secondly, you do not fit a distribution to data by fitting its pdf to a histogram. There are several approaches to parameter estimation, the most common is "maximum likelihood". According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Maximum_likelihood), the maximum likelihood estimator of lambda is the inverse of the sample mean, or in Matlab notation:

```
lambda_est = 1 / mean(x)
```

To get a rough idea whether describing your data by this distribution makes sense, you can then plot the pdf using the estimated parameter over the (normalized) histogram, or over a nonparametric density estimate like that given by `ksdensity`.